# Building a survey app for Android with a listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Say if I was to make an app for Android that pulls data from a server which contains a list of surveys, each survey containing a set of questions and each question has a set of options (or answers)

Now I'm thinking to implement each survey using a listview, each row(item) in the list view will display one question and each question will display a set of answers.

The first problem is to do with the type of question...a question might be of the binary answer format, so "Are you male?" then two options "yes" and "no" this can be an xml layout for that type of question. But then there is other type of questions, like "Describe your time in London" with an EditText as the option. The harder part comes when I don't know how many options are to be viewed inside a listItem (row) of the listview, say one question can be "Your favourite foods" and the list of options can be checkboxes, so "Pizza", "bacon", "wedges". This is a 3 option type of quuestion, but what if I have the same type of question but with, say 7 options.

How can I make an XML layout that will adapt to the number of options to a particular question?

thanks in advance.

Comment: just show one question at a time, that's better for not polluting your  user with bias inducing factors like other questions with interesting keywords, worries over long surveys, etc.

Comment: You would need to construct your layout dynamically in code based on some meta-data about the question. So you'd need to (in code) examine the type of question, and then dynamically create the list item layout for that particular question.

Comment: @unluddite I have thought about that solution and I might actually be able to pull it off, however I was also thinking to put a listview insie a listview to display the options but I thought that would be too costly on the cpu

Comment: I don't know if it'll be costly in terms of CPU, but certainly costly to your sanity. A simple Linear or Relative Layout would do just fine, IMHO.